# To check whether a file has been downloaded or not via protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Need help to check whether a file has been successfully downloaded or not in a specified folder.
The file name dynamically changes every time a new file is downloaded but the initial part of the file "Pivot_Report" always stays the same

The actual file gets downloaded in the mentioned folder but protractor is not able to find it with just the initial part of the full name

This is the code I'm using (filenamePath is '/Users/Shubh/Documents/')

```
browser.driver.wait(function() {
        var fileName = filenamePath+"*.csv"
        var filesArray = glob.sync(fileName)
        if (typeof filesArray !== 'undefined' && filesArray.length > 0){
          return filesArray
        }
      }, 10000).then(function(filesArray) {
        var fileWithPath = filesArray[0]
        var temp = fileWithPath.indexOf("Pivot_Report")
        expect(fileWithPath.indexOf("Pivot_Report") >= 0).toBe(true,'Pivot Download is not succesfull')
        if(fs1.existsSync(fileWithPath)){
          fs1.unlinkSync(fileWithPath)
        }
      })
```

Getting the timeout error

Answer (score 0):

It happens, because your path is incorrect.

I think easiest way is to use `path.resolve()` :

```
var path = require("path");

var filenamePath = path.resolve("Users/Shubh/Documents");
```

and then you will have (notice that you missed a `/` before `*.csv`)

```
var fileName = filenamePath+"/*.csv"
```

Comment: Hi, Still No Go. var filenamePath=downloadPath
        browser.driver.wait(function() {
          var fileName = filenamePath+"/.csv"
          var filesArray = glob.sync(fileName)
          if (typeof filesArray !== 'undefined' && filesArray.length > 0){
            return filesArray
          }
        }, 10000)